# Using setTimeout and setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to call a function with in 30 seconds when I initially load the page. Thereafter it should be called in 60 seconds automatically.

What i did is,

```
  <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
        setTimeout('ajaxload()',30000);
        setInterval('ajaxload()',60000);
        function ajaxload()
        {
         //code
        }
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

But The function is called in irregular times, i think. Am I doing correct? If any mistake kindly share....

Comment: The seconds were called using php code. I didnt shared for simplifying the code.

Comment: How irregular? Currently, it'll call it at 30, 60, 120, 180... Make it smaller numbers so you can confirm? Also, it's better to write `30 * 1000`, 30k is not bad but especially with bigger numbers it's just unreadable. It sounds like you may have checked but are you sure PHP code is right?

Comment: By the way, your closing `</body>` tag is in the wrong place, should be before `</html>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using it a bit incorrectly. If the first one is at 30 secs and thereafter at 60 secs you should do it in sequence.

```
setTimeout(startAjaxLoad,30000);

function ajaxload()
{
     //code
}

function startAjaxLoad() 
{
    ajaxload();
    setInterval(ajaxload,60000);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Don't pass a string .. pass the function name/declaration itself:

```
setTimeout(function () {
   ajaxload();
   setInterval(ajaxload, 60000);
}, 30000);
```

Comment: This is absolutely the correct response.  Proper use of setTimeout and setInterval as well as use of anonymous function instead of a string.

Only thing I would do is assign the setInterval to a variable so it can be cancelled at a later time, if required.

Answer (score 0):

change to

```
setTimeout(function(){ajaxload()},30000);
setInterval(function(){ajaxload()},60000);
function ajaxload()
        {
         //code
        }
```

Comment: There's no need for the anonymous functions.  You can just pass ajaxload directly as a reference here and this doesn't solve any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider something a little tidier if you're going to continuously call an AJAX method, by waiting for it to finish first and then simply using `setTimeout()` again.

```
function ajaxload()
{
    $.ajax({

        // AJAX Settings.
        // ...

        complete: function()
        {
            // Call .ajaxload() 60 seconds from the completion of this request.
            setTimeout(ajaxload, 60000);
        }

    });
}



// Initial call.
setTimeout(ajaxload, 30000);
```